# Failed to run app copied from my jailbreaked iPhone 5s on Simulator offerred by Xcode 5.1

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, jailbreak

- Scenario:

  - Simulator cannot download and install apps from App Store;
  - We can test our apps through Xcode during the development phase, and the test app's file is saved in Directory: ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/(eg.9E3CD45XXXXXXX)
  - I have a jailbreaked iPhone and install a third party app: SKYPE
    which is installed at: var/mobile/Applications/A6D3E4XXXX/
  - What I have Done:

  ***  I copied this (/A6D3E4XXXX) directory to the simulators corresponding position, ie, now there is a directory of ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/A6D3E4XXXX in my mac's file system;
  ***  And I run the simulator, and there is A SKYPE icon in the system, while I tap it to open, it just get stuck and failed.

  - Any ideas for this issue? Appreciated!

Yeah! For short, I want my apps from my iPhone run on my Simulator from Mac. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Apps which run on a device are compiled for the ARM CPU architecture and apps which run on the iPhone Simulator are compiled for the i386 CPU architecture.  I expect that has something to do with this.

Answer (score 1):

What a great big surprise.

Simulator and device binaries are built with a different compiler for a different instruction set architecture. They are not compatible with each other.

This is never going to work.

You can't really avoid having real devices to test with - not least to check performance and usability.   What is possible is re-signing (your own) app-store builds with an team or enterprise key to allow that to be tested on devices before submission.